# How to move my Asynchronous Facebook SDK script to service/factory module?

Tags: angularjs

Once I heard about Angular and read the docs, fell in love with it. So I read about the 11 steps tutorial of Angularjs and now I'm trying to build an app with Facebook SDK. My subject states it all, but I will further explain.

The code below, I have that on my html view/partial view. I want to move that chunk of code to a service or factory module.

```
  // Init the SDK upon load
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
       appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
       channelUrl : 'channel.html', // Path to your Channel File
       status     : true, // check login status
       cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
       xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML
      });

     angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
   };

   // Load the SDK Asynchronously
   (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
```

Even though my current code is working I'm a bit irritated because I would like my view if possible to only contain html codes. Also I think its a best practice. :). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would build a factory that returns a promise that's resolved when the SDK is loaded. Something like:

```
(function (window) {
    "use strict";

    var angular = window.angular;
    angular.module('facebookService', []).factory('FacebookService', [
    '$q','$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
        function init() {
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                defer.resolve();
            });
         }
         var defer = $q.defer();
         defer.promise.then(function () {
             // FB.Init...
            window.FB = 'Facebook SDK loaded'; // Remove this line
         });

         window.fbAsyncInit = angular.bind(this, init);

         return defer;
    }]);
}(window));
```

Now you can just inject the sevice and append method on the pomise using `FacebookService.promise.then(...)`

Here's a example http://jsfiddle.net/fredrik/f4tkA/

Answer (score -1):

You should look at the Angular seed project for good structuring practise:

https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

You could create it as a service (above) or you could have it run when your app loads once. If you need to reuse the code then build it as a service or directive:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
       .run([ '$q','$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope){
        }]);}
```

You can view a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/raff77/53SwK/) but will have to enter you API keys for Facebook to get it to work.